# how to zoom and pan a simple imageview using matrix

Tags: android, matrix, zooming, pan

I got frustated with zooming and panning issue of an image in android.I dont want to use sony zoom tutorial because i need zoom from buttons.

can anybody suggests me or provide me code to zoom an image with simple matrix calculation.

please do needful.